# Get ID of first statement and post it in the second

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql-insert-id

I have a script that creates an user in the database:

```
  if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
    $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);
    if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
      header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
      exit();
    }
  }
  header('Location: ./register_success.php');
  exit();
```

The table members also haves an ID column which is unique and auto increment.

After the user is created I want to run a new statement.

```
 if ($insert_stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_id, username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
    $insert_stmt2->bind_param('sssss', $user_id, $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);
```

This time I have a new column named user_id. I want to get the inserted ID of the first INSERT and insert it as user_id into the second table.

Does someone know how I can do that?

**Edit 1:**

```
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
    $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);
    // Execute the prepared query.
    if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
        header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
        exit();
    }
    if ($insert_stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_id, username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
        $insert_stmt2->bind_param('sssss', $mysqli->insert_id, $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);
        // Execute the prepared query.
        if (! $insert_stmt2->execute()) {
            header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
            exit();
        }
    }
}
header('Location: ./register_success.php');
exit();
```

Comment: Use the [`$mysqli->insert_id`](http://php.net/mysqli_insert_id) property after executing your first INSERT statement.

Comment: RTM, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: So in my case I need to replace `$user_id` with `$insert_stmt->insert_id`?

Comment: No, `insert_id` is a property of your *connection*, not of your *statement*. So you'll need to use `$mysqli->insert_id`.

Comment: But I am using `$mysqli->prepare` in the first and second statement. If I use `$mysqli->insert_id` it will select the insert_id of the second statement

Comment: It shouldn't. The property is filled when you call `$insert_stmt->execute()` and should only be overwritten once you call `$insert_stmt2->execute()`. So in `$insert_stmt2->bind_param()` it should point to the auto increment value generated by your first `$insert_stmt`.

Comment: The statement: 
`$insert_stmt2->bind_param('sssss', $mysqli->insert_id, $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);` did not create a new row in the database

Comment: See edit 1 in my first post. The second statement is not creating a row

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the $mysqli->insert_id after your first statement and before your second statement. Then it is available for your second statement.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);
$stmt->execute();
$user_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
    
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_id, username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssss', $user_id, $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: If you are answering a duplicated question, at least make your code sensible